# Spring - Direct all outbound traffic via a proxy

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, proxy

I have a Spring app using spring-ws for all my SOAP messages working just fine on my local development machine.  When I deploy to a server that requires the use of a proxy for any traffic to reach the outside world I appear to be stuck.  I was under the impression I can set some JVM arguments such as

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName 
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

But the class files do not seem to be honoring the proxyUser and proxyPassword arguments.

I even took a step further and implemented it within the java code itself:

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
```

But still no luck.

I've then tried to use the java.net.Authenticator to set the username and password but that does not appear to work either:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(
                  new Authenticator() {
                    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                      return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
                    }
                  }
                );
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to route all traffic through a proxy using Java6, Tomcat 6 and Spring 3(with spring-ws)

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out it wasn't honoring the passed in JVM HTTP arguments because my web service is using HTTPS.  After setting the flags to the following:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhostURL 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=someUserName 
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

All worked as planned.

Comment: I suspect this only worked through a plain Proxy Server, NOT an authenticated one.  'https.proxyUser' and 'https.proxyPassword' are not JVM args AFAIK...